# White status bar in iOS Phonegap?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, statusbar

how to make top status bar translucent with white text in Phonegap 3.1.0 for iOS7?

App looks fine in mobile Safari, but when I try to run it in Phonegap text at top bar is white only while app loading, after that it's black no matter what settings I set in project's config.

Right now have `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">` in web page & 'Status Bar Style' = 'Black Translucent' in XCode... doesn't help.

Pls help!

Answer (score 25):

You can do this without any meta tags or editing anything in XCode.

First, install the statusbar plugin via CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Then you can use these preferences to style the status bar (in config.xml):

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

This will give you a transparent bar in iOS 7 with white text. For other options check out http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.statusbar

Comment: This should be the recommended answer as easier to maintain.

Comment: All the plugins got renamed, so this should be `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar` now.

Comment: `blacktranslucent` didn't work for me, but `default` did and statusbar became black translucent

Answer (score 10):

finally, I found solution.

Make sure you have following:
At your index.html have following meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

At Xcode, open [YourPrjectName].plist & add following lines:

> "Status bar style" = "Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)" AND
>   "View controller-based status bar appearance" = "NO"

Without second line in will not work (actually, that was the issue in my case).

Comment: Didn't work for me, sadly — statusbar is still transparent with black text

Comment: Yes, solves the white status bar issue after doing this to show the status bar perfectly in iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18886468/706751

Comment: I've actually had to change a setting in the MainViewController.xib file using Xcode - the 4th tabicon over (the one that looks like a slider, to the right of the ruler) has options like Size, Orientation, Status Bar, Top Bar, etc. - down below those, right above the Tint color option, is Background -- Change it to black! :)

Answer (score 2):

if you use phonegap build, you can call

```
StatusBar.styleLightContent();
```

https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link below, hope this could help you.

http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/

Comment: Chrome says this site contains malware

Answer (score 1):

May be too late, but someone else with the same question may resolve this by installing below plugin.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-disable-ios11-statusbar --save`

Then build and run the app the issue will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Add this one

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
      document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
   }
 }

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

## The Status Bar Issue in iOS7

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I want to achieve. I want the top bar to be:
1. **translucent**, so the top bar will be 'same color' as anything beneath it;
2. **with white font**...

I have both when I run my app in Safari... But when I run it within  PhoneGap, the top bar's font color is **black**. How to make it **white**?

Comment: Try this may be help 1)http://alexvanderzon.com/metatags/ (2)http://maximilianhoffmann.com/article/building-ios-web-apps/ (3)http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Answer (score 0):

I figured a more up to date answer may help someone here, this works in cordova 3.7+ and iOS 8.x and negates the need for the extra plugin.

In your project's plist file make sure that "Status bar is initially hidden" and "View controller-based status bar appearance" are both set to "NO"

Then, in MainViewController.m, inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` add:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
```

for white or black text in your status bar.

Alternatively to hide completely, set both plist attributes above to YES, which appears to work for hiding it.