# hide status bar iPad iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, statusbar

I read lot's of answers how to hide status bar on iPad in iOS 7.0 but nothing works. My app is an iPhone app only, and it's deployment target is set to 6.0 . On iPhone 6.0 , 7.0 and iPad 6.0 status bar is hidden, but on iPad with iOS 7.0 isn't.

[image: my info.plist]

[image: app screen (iPad iOS 7.0)]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar won't disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)

Answer (score 0):

Try these properties in the plist also for iPad 7.0

Status bar is initially hidden = YES

View controller-based status bar appearance = NO

Comment: it's in my -Info.plist too

Comment: What about? [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

Comment: it was set as YES, when i change to NO nothing happens. In my .plist : status bar is initially hidden = YES ; View controller-based status bar appearance = NO ;

Comment: I have the same problem. Using the same setting as Igor. Works for iphone but not for ipad

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**Option1:**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```

Use this code in the rootViewController of your app

**Option 2:**

In info.plist file add a row for "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to *NO*

**Option 3:**

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

       [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;

        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    }
```

Comment: This method is inside my rootViewController and this key is already inside my plist(See screenshot).

Comment: Check out this link, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886195/ios-7-status-bar-overlapping-ui?lq=1

Comment: i can change this annoying status bar style to other, but still cannot hide it

Comment: I've tried all of this as well. it works on iphone but does not work on ipad

Answer (score 0):

Try if add this to hide the status bar if you use "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO.

```
AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this snippet:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]){
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
}
else{
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this method to your `ViewController` , it worked for me

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```