# override safeAreaInsets for WKWebView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am trying to make WKWebView full screen in iOS. I found an answer in Swift, [make WKWebview "real" fullscreen on iPhone X (remove safe area from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244002/make-wkwebview-real-fullscreen-on-iphone-x-remove-safe-area-from-wkwebview)

Unfortunately, I need to use Objective-C this time.

Please help to convert the Swift code below to Objective-C

```
class FullScreenWKWebView: WKWebView {
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Or if there is any other better ways to do it in Objective-C.

Thanks.

Comment: To translate from Swift to Objective-C, _learn_ whichever language you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Objective-C translation for the code in your question:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface FullScreenWKWebView : WKWebView
@end

@implementation FullScreenWKWebView

- (UIEdgeInsets)safeAreaInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

@end
```

Comment: You can also just return UIEdgeInsetsZero.