# iOS: Make WebView fullscreen (hide white background behind home button)

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, wkwebview, home-button

New to iOS development.

ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         WebView(url: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
    }
}
```

WebView.swift:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url) else {
            return WKWebView();
        }
              
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let wkWebView = WKWebView()
        wkWebView.load(request)
        wkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        return wkWebView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
      
    }
}
```

results in a white bar behind the home button indicator:

[image: white bar]

How can I make the webview fullscreen so that there is no more white bar behind the home button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set bottom space of Your WebView not to Safe Area but to Superview
Select View here

[storyboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxfKu.png)

for SwiftUI version just do

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         WebView(url: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom])
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I get there with Xcode? Is this even available with Swift?

Comment: @Hillcow it is swift.

Comment: its Swift + SwiftUI instead of Swift + UIKit

Comment: I needed to add `webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`. Stolened from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244002/make-wkwebview-real-fullscreen-on-iphone-x-remove-safe-area-from-wkwebview