# WKWebView bottom constraint set but doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have set the `WKWebView` bottom constraint to super view but it won't display till super view instead displays content till safe area.

Here is the problem image that displays the bottom part doesn't fill properly.

[image]

And here is the hierarchy of view and constraints image

[image]

[image]

And code to setup WebView constraints with the container view

```
    let wv = WKWebView(frame: containerView.frame, configuration: wvConfig)
    webView = wv
    containerView.addSubview(wv)
    
    // setup constraints
    wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        wv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
```

So, Can anyone rectify the issue here?

> Some certain URL's works, but not for all. Why?

Comment: Could you specify with background colors or whatever if the issue is in the added view or if it in the parent view?

Comment: What does the else case?? You create some constraints thad do nothing, I thing you should assign the constraints into variables and then add the variables to the view 
with self.view.addConstraint(constY)

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ.else case too working fine just that bottom part doesn't seem over safe area. isActive means to add constraints in view. I think you should check doc regarding that

Comment: Could the problem be in the container view instead of the web view? As others have suggested, you can try setting a red background for the container view and see if the view covers the whole screen or not.

Comment: @Cristik Already tried that and check that constraint screenshot and first constraint, its already attached with superview bottom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following subclassed WKWebView might solve your problem:

```
class FullScreenWKWebView: WKWebView {

    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let insects = super.safeAreaInsets
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: insects.top, left: insects.left, bottom: 0, right: insects.right)
        } else {
            return .zero
        }

    }
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets{
        let insects = super.alignmentRectInsets
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: insects.top-20, left: insects.left, bottom: 0, right: insects.right)
    }
}
```

The above snipped taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269426/2299040)

Full Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class FullScreenWKWebView: WKWebView {

    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let insects = super.safeAreaInsets
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: insects.top, left: insects.left, bottom: 0, right: insects.right)
        } else {
            return .zero
        }

    }
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets{
        let insects = super.alignmentRectInsets
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: insects.top-20, left: insects.left, bottom: 0, right: insects.right)
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let contaienrView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let webView: FullScreenWKWebView = {
        let v = FullScreenWKWebView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    func setupViews(){
        view.addSubview(contaienrView)
        contaienrView.addSubview(webView)
        let constrains = [
            contaienrView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            contaienrView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            contaienrView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            contaienrView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contaienrView.topAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contaienrView.leadingAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contaienrView.bottomAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contaienrView.trailingAnchor),
            ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constrains)
    }

    func loadRequest(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://afghan-gps.com/mobile")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        loadRequest()
    }
}
```

output: 1. iOS version > 10
[image]

2. iOS version <11
   [image]

Comment: the thing is, I only need bottom constraints to not use safe area but top to use it

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 you can adjust the value of  safeAreaInsets in FullScreenWKWebView according to your requirement

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 give me a minute

Comment: But my question is if containerview is in storyboard than how does it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198475/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-ei-captain-v2-0).

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to reproduce the same issue, used your approach but didn't get any issue regarding bottom space.

```
class TestWebViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

var wkWebView : WKWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addWKWebView()

    wkWebView?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    wkWebView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func addWKWebView() {
    let wvConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration.init()
    let wv = WKWebView(frame: containerView.frame, configuration: wvConfig)
    wkWebView = wv
    containerView.addSubview(wv)
    // setup constraints
    wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        wv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
}
```

[image: View Hierarchy]
[image: Constraints]

Everything is working fine for me.

Output -

[image: Output]

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

**UPDATE** -

Issue is with scrollView of WKWebview.

In safe area WKScrollView.adjustedContentInset is set to {0, 0, 34, 0}.

To avoid this use

```
wv.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Final output -

[image]

Comment: Yes, but isn't the same thing I have done in question?

Comment: pls check the edited question and use URL that I provided and let me know

Comment: Finally I find out what is the issue, please check updated answer.

Comment: But top insets doesn't perform well with this scnario

Comment: the last one save my life, thx

Answer (score -1):

Replace containerview with view in bottom constraint because root is view.

```
 view.addSubview(wv)

  wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        wv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        wv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: wv, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: But ContainerView is already attached with `superview.bottom`. So, why we need this?

Comment: i updated my answer. we have to just change in bottom anchor. you are setting constraint with containerview. set this to view which is root element

Comment: replace containerView.addSubview(wv) with view.addSubview(wv). beacuse container view is like safe area

Comment: bro its not like safe area. Please check screenshot for constraints. Container view is attached with superview's bottom.

Comment: check out the difference of containerview and view it will help to solve this out

Answer (score -1):

your code looks fine, your problem might come from the `containerView` constraints.

If you are using storyboards, Xcode is probably setting constraints on safe area. In that case you should handle all the constraints programmatically.

Comment: That's not possible. If we give constraint to container view bottom with safe area bottom then whatever it is (storyboard or coding), it makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

According to the given screenshot, bottom constraint is applied in to safe area.Add bottom constraint into SuperView.  [image]

Comment: Already tried that and check that constraint screenshot and first constraint, its already attached with superview bottom

Comment: I think your bottom constraint is applied in to ContainerView bottom. It needs to be applied in to SuperView, Plz check

Comment: Pls check the screenshot above code, its applied to bottom of superview

Comment: Can you Change Bottom Alignment Constraint - > First item into ContainerView.Bottom  and Second Item into Superview.Bottom (Reverse first item and second item i)