# How to add margin at top of WKWebView in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am showing a pdf file in WKWebView in IOS swift, and it showing fine. I am loading pdf file from server. But some part of file is being hidden behind top navigation bar. I want to add margin at top of WKWebView. Here is my current code.

```
    let myBlog = file
    let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    // init and load request in webview.
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)

    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    // webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // webView.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])

    self.view.addSubview(sv)       
    let pdfVC = UIViewController()
    pdfVC.view.addSubview(webView)
    pdfVC.title = "File"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)
```

[image]

Here the commented code is how I am trying to add margin and not working.

Comment: Try to change this line as, webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame - 64)

Comment: to set frame of WKWebView refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421548/ios-wkwebview-status-bar-padding)

Answer (score 1):

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

In the line above set frame such that it leaves margin from top and reduce the given margin from the height.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting layoutMargin, It should solve the issue.

`self.webView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `webView` to `false`, i.e.

```
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Now, add proper **`constraints`** of `webView` to `view's` `safeAreaLayoutGuide` or `layoutMarginsGuide`, i.e

```
    var guide: UILayoutGuide
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        guide = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor),
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add top margin by using the following line

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - 40)
```