# Phonegap build IOS App works since this week not correct

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

Since some days all my Phonegap build IOS Apps works not correct.
The statusbar is overlaying the header but if I close the app an open again the statusbar is correct. Also if try to open the camera or something like that it only works if I close and open the app again

Comment: it is the same code I use for the app and there was never a problem with it. Since last build all funtions from the plugins works only if I close and open the app or If open the spotlight search or do something like that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one helps?

```
function onDeviceReady() {
if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
      document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
   } 
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

got it from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18912574/59689

Or that solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5cjphChWwY

Comment: This time it must be a different bug... The status bar and all the other plugins works only after I switch to another app and than I go back it works. (camera, geolocation, statusbar, social sharing, and so on...) works only if I close and open again or if I open the spotlight search from ios

Comment: maybe because the code is executed before the divice was ready?